# How to dynamically add new drool rules to a kie Container without recompiling all rules

Tags: java, spring-boot, drools, kie

I wanted to know if i can dynamically update rules in a kie container .

Scenario:
I have a global KieFileSystem and every time a new rule is added i am writing to this file System. After that i am creating a Kie Module using KieBuilder using the updated KieFileSystem.Then i am using the Release Id of this kie Module to update my kie container to Version using updateToVersion()
Using drools and kie version 8.31.0.Final

Problem:
For large number of complex rules updateToversion is recomiling all rules including the previously compiled ones in the kie container thereby increasing execution time.

Requirement:
I want to add the new rules to the kie container without recompiling the already compiled rules.

My approach to this problem :
Creating a new FileSystem when a new rule is added containing only the new rule and use this file system to add to a global list of  kieContainers by creating a new container everytime a rule is added.  During rule execution I am executing all the containers in the list. This is not a good approach as it involves creation of several containers

I would like to know if it is possible to do this operation in a more efficient way .

THANKS IN ADVANCE